# Common MACROS for C# Project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have converted a VS 2019 using .NET 4.8 csproj file to VS 2022 using .NET 5.0
Everything builds however my post processing command fails.

It uses `$(TargetPath)` which seems to be no longer available.

What do we use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here [PostEvents](https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert/issues/269)

in other words take a copy of your `PostBuild` event script, edit your project file and delete the `PostBuild` event section. The open the project file in Visual Studio and recreate the `PostBuild` event. This will create it using `Targets`